# How to order by alphabetically row-wise?

Tags: sql

I have a relation like following

```
    r1                  r2
1   Ashley              Chris Jackson
2   Chris Jackson       Brittany Harris
```

I want to resulted pairs to be ordered alphabetically in rows, like

```
      r1                  r2
1   Ashley              Chris Jackson
2   Brittany Harris     Chris Jackson
```

This is a toy example, real table is larger

Comment: `order by col1, col2`?

Comment: @mattytommo I guess that only order column-wise instead of row-wise

Comment: Can you explain why you're doing this? There might be a more logical way of doing whatever it is you're trying to accomplish in the end. Normally one does not "order the column values" in a set. Each individual column should have a specific meaning, without values being tossed around in ABC order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT r1,r2 FROM mytable WHERE r1<r2
UNION
SELECT r2,r1 FROM mytable WHERE r1>=r2;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eff00/8)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to rearrange your colunms depending on which comes first alphabetically?  If so, here's one option using `case`:

```
select case when r1 > r2 then r2 else r1 end as r1,
       case when r1 <= r2 then r2 else r1 end as r2
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6bb5/2)